# Working with JSON arrays in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, dynatree

I am trying to use a JSON array structure to populate a dynatree. Perhaps I need to change this structure to facilitate this?  Here's the JSON I'm responding to an ajax call:

[image: JSON Array]

As you can see, I have an array of testSteps (0 being 001016..., 1 being 001024..., etc). The key of each is the test name. The value is another JSON array of the actual steps (Additional testing..., Order sent..., etc).

I need to get these values so that I can build a dynatree like this:

[image: Test steps tree]

I'm running jQuery code to try to get the test names (haven't gotten to the steps after this yet):

```
$.get('ReportSpecimenProcessingServlet', {specimenNumber: specimenNumber}, function(responseJson) { 
var testingNode = $("#tree").dynatree("getTree").selectKey("testing");
testingNode.removeChildren();
var steps = responseJson.testSteps;
//numTests += steps.length;
$.each(steps, function(data) {
    testingNode.addChild({
      title: data,
      isFolder: true
    });
});
```

When I look at the console, I see this for "steps":

> [Object { 001016 - Calcium, Serum=[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eezs6.png)}, Object { 001024 - Phosphorus, Serum=[5]}, Object { 001032 - Glucose, Serum=[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eezs6.png)},...

and this is what my tree looks like:

[image: Testing tree]

Can anyone help me with how to get JSON array values via jQuery? I can get the Dynatree nodes if I can just get the values...

EDIT:  Adding some raw JSON:

```
{"testSteps":[{"001016 - Calcium, Serum":["Additional testing received from LCLS at 17-APR-2014 01:40:37.356399 - status A","Order sent to DI at 17-APR-2014 01:42:00.351891 - status S"]},{"001024 - Phosphorus, Serum":["Additional testing received from LCLS at 17-APR-2014 01:40:37.652686 - status A","Order sent to DI at 17-APR-2014 01:42:00.203879 - status S","Results received from DI at 17-APR-2014 14:16:35.960787 - status P","Results sent to LCLS at 17-APR-2014 14:16:51.497767 - status W","Successful response from LCLS at 17-APR-2014 14:16:57.476592 - status I"]}
```

Also, I have made progress with new jQuery code:

```
            $.each(responseJson.testSteps, function() {
            $.each(this, function(k,v) {
                console.log("Key " + k + ' Value ' + v);
                testingNode.addChild({
                  title: k,
                  isFolder: true    //test (steps will not be folders)
                });
            });
        });
```

which gets me this:

[image: Tree with test names]

Comment: Can you post the raw JSON code, not the whole thing, but in text format just a few entries.

Comment: Yes, all the values start as strings, associated by JSON array.

Comment: Here is some raw JSON: {"testSteps":[{"001016 - Calcium, Serum":["Additional testing received from LCLS at 17-APR-2014 01:40:37.356399 - status A","Order sent to DI at 17-APR-2014 01:42:00.351891 - status S"]},{"001024 - Phosphorus, Serum":["Additional testing received from LCLS at 17-APR-2014 01:40:37.652686 - status A","Order sent to DI at 17-APR-2014 01:42:00.203879 - status S","Results received from DI at 17-APR-2014 14:16:35.960787 - status P","Results sent to LCLS at 17-APR-2014 14:16:51.497767 - status W","Successful response from LCLS at 17-APR-2014 14:16:57.476592 - status I"]},

Comment: I have just now gotten further by using this, so may be on track:       $.each(responseJson.testSteps, function() {
       $.each(this, function(k,v) {
        console.log(k + ' ' + v);
       });
      });

Comment: @Mark please put the JSON and any other code that you create into your original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work (breakthrough after this post) - hope it will help others.

I changed my jQuery code to:

```
            $.each(responseJson.testSteps, function() {
            $.each(this, function(k,v) {
                console.log("Key " + k + ' Value ' + v);
                var testNode = testingNode.addChild({
                  title: k,
                  isFolder: true    //test (steps will not be folders)
                });
                $.each(v, function(key,val) {
                    testNode.addChild({
                        title: val
                    });
                });
            });
```

which got me this:

[image]

Thanks to those who had comments - I appreciate the quick help.